# ms access query choosing soonest of two date values

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have the following table in an MS Access 2010 database:

```
CommTable  
    pkID  
    fkID  
    Level  
    type1Date  
    type2Date
```

I need to select Level and the soonest of the values in the two date fields for a given value of fkID.  Here is some pseudocode for what the SQL might look like:

```
SELECT Level, date FROM CommTable WHERE fkID=2  
If Type1Date<Type2Date{date=Type1Date}  
Else {date=Type2Date}
```

This is obviously not correct SQL.  Can someone show me the correct syntax for writing this in MS Access SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use [Iif](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-fonction-HA001228853.aspx), but I must admit I'm not sure that you can have fields as `truepart` / `falsepart`

```
select level, Iif(type1Date < type2Date, type1Date, type2Date)
FROM CommTable
WHERE fkID=2;
```

you may try also (but again, I can't test it, and not sure if you can use UNION in a subquery in access).

```
select a.level, min(a.dte)
FROM
(select level, type1Date as dte
 FROM CommTable WHERE fkId =2
 UNION
 select level, type2Date as dte
 FROM CommTable WHERE fkId = 2
 ) as a
 GROUP BY a.level
```

Comment: +1 for the fast response.  The date comparison works, and thank you for reminding me about Iif.  I did not know Iif is part of SQL, but I use it in VBA.  Your response does not return a date value.  How do you alter your code to return the soonest of the two date values along with Level?

Comment: @CodeMed Well, I ain't got an access... to Access. What does my answer return , then ? just a string 'type1Date' or 'type2Date' ?

Comment: Your code returns two columns.  Level and Expr1001.  Level has a value, but Expr1001 is empty.  Perhaps Access cannot read dates in Iif after all.

Comment: Thank you.  Your edit works.  However, I needed to add part of jas0501's suggestion to get the field name to print out properly.

Answer (score 2):

minor tweak to provide date field name

```
select
  Level
, iif(type1Date < type2Date, type1Date, type2Date) as [date]
from CommTable
where fkID = 2
```

Comment: Thank you.  +1 for showing how to get the field name.  I did end up using the UNION approach instead of Iif, though.